# Duplicate a line in TXT file and increase number inside it every time it duplicates

Tags: python, string, loops, integer, txt

Let's say I have this line in TXT file:

```
ABCD1EFGH
```

What I want to do is repeat the line for an amount number of times but the number 1 will increase by 1 every time it duplicates.
like that:

```
ABCD1EFGH
ABCD2EFGH
ABCD3EFGH
ABCD4EFGH
```

What is the code for Python to do so?

I haven't tried any method yet, I have no clue.

Comment: Are there other lines after the one that you want to duplicate? Do not forget a text file is a sequential file... BTW, you should try something and show your best attempt. Read again (?) [ask] if you wonder why.

Comment: if the number always prefixed and suffixed by exactly 4 characters? Or you have to find the position of the number?

Answer (score 0):

I'll let the part of reading from a file and writing back to it as an exercise for you.

Also according to your example I assume the number is prefixed and suffixed by exactly 4 characters

```
txt = "ABCD1EFGH"
number = int(txt[4])
for i in range(12):
    print(f"{txt[:4]}{number + i}{txt[5:]}")

ABCD1EFGH
ABCD2EFGH
ABCD3EFGH
ABCD4EFGH
ABCD5EFGH
ABCD6EFGH
ABCD7EFGH
ABCD8EFGH
ABCD9EFGH
ABCD10EFGH
ABCD11EFGH
ABCD12EFGH
```

Comment: Simple and easy, the read and write part  was nice toch.

Answer (score 0):

In case the input string is of indeterminate length, with the following structure `LETTERS` then `NUMBER(S)` then `LETTERS` again, the following function would do what you want. Note that you can use REGEX as well, and the function can be simplified quite a bit. I'm opting for the longer version so you can see what is being done.

```py
def inc_number(astring: str) -> str:
    start = None
    end = None
    for i, c in enumerate(astring):
        if c.isnumeric():
            start = i
            break
    for i, c in enumerate(astring[start:]):
        if not c.isnumeric():
            end = i+start
            break
    start_string = astring[:start]
    number = int(astring[start:end])+1
    end_string = astring[end:]
    result = f"{start_string}{number}{end_string}"
    return result
    

astring = "ABCD1EFGH"
for i in range(5):
    astring = inc_number(astring)
    print(astring)

astring = "thisistext41thisismoretext"
for i in range(5):
    astring = inc_number(astring)
    print(astring)
```

Output:

```
ABCD2EFGH
ABCD3EFGH
ABCD4EFGH
ABCD5EFGH
ABCD6EFGH
thisistext42thisismoretext
thisistext43thisismoretext
thisistext44thisismoretext
thisistext45thisismoretext
thisistext46thisismoretext
```

Comment: This is nice approach 
I haven't thought of that 
thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
def duplicate_and_increase_number(line, amount):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, amount + 1):
        new_line = line.replace('1', str(i), 1)
        result.append(new_line)
    return result

content = 'ABCD1EFGH'
duplicates = duplicate_and_increase_number(content, 4)  # Change 4 to the desired amount
for text in duplicates:
    print(text)
```

Output:

```
ABCD1EFGH
ABCD2EFGH
ABCD3EFGH
ABCD4EFGH
```

Answer (score 0):

***INPUT file.txt:***

```
ABCD1EFGH
EFGH33ABCD
```

***CODE:***

```
import re

# Specify how many modified rows you want to get
ITER = 4


with open("test.txt", "r+", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    promo_codes = f.readlines()

    for p_c in promo_codes:
        num = int(re.search(r"(?![A-Z]{4})(\d{1,})", p_c).group(1))
        end_num = num + ITER
        l_chips = re.search(r"(^[A-Z]{4})", p_c).group(1)
        r_chips = re.search(r"\d([A-Z]{4}?)", p_c).group(1)

        while num < end_num:
            num += 1
            print(f"{l_chips}{num}{r_chips}", file=f)
```

***OUTPUT file.txt:***

```
ABCD1EFGH
EFGH33ABCD
ABCD2EFGH
ABCD3EFGH
ABCD4EFGH
ABCD5EFGH
EFGH34ABCD
EFGH35ABCD
EFGH36ABCD
EFGH37ABCD
```

Comment: Good luck!
@Ahmed , choose an answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way too.The code is simply based on nested looping.

1. Original content of file:

```
ABC12EFG
HIJ4KLM
```

2. Input:

```
t=int(input("no.of loops="))
m=open("demofile3.txt","r")
a=m.readlines()
b=a
for i in range(0,t):
    a=b
    b=[]
    for j in a:
        print(j)
        p=""
        d=0
        f=0
        for k in range(0,len(j)):
            if j[k].isnumeric():
                    if j[k+1].isnumeric():
                      f=10*int(j[k])
                      d=d+f
                    else:
                      d=d+int(j[k])
                      p=p+str(d+1)
            else:
                p=p+j[k]
        b.append(p)
```

3. Output(when loop is run 3 times):

```
ABC12EFG
HIJ4KLM
ABC13EFG
HIJ5KLM
ABC14EFG
HIJ6KLM
```

Hope it helped :)